# solr filter query contains space and dash would not return result

Tags: solr

i have a solr query has the following filter query:

fq= category:Footwear - Men's

I know i need to escape spaces and special solr char in there so I turn the java string into:

Footwear// //-// Men's
(replace all ' ' into '// ' and all '-' into '//-'

but did not work.
can someone tell me what did i do wrong?

thanks!

Comment: fyi the query would look like:
fq=sub_cat_str%3AFootwear/%20%2F-/+Road

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use \ instead of /, as \ is the escape character.

So that is: `Footwear\\ \\-\\ Men's`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the java client for connecting and querying your SOLR index I suggest using the `ClientUtils` class to escape  your input.